# Is there any canvas/layout editor in Javascript or PHP for defining custom document layouts?

Tags: php, javascript, layout, html, editor

I'm trying to develop a invoice printing module for the application we're creating (in PHP & Javascript). The thing is... I want our clients to be able to customise their invoice output as in being able to choose where to put their logo and header, how to organize their data output, etc.

I know how I want to do it, but what I don't know is how to put it into practice, so my question is: is there any Javascript or PHP class/module providing an editable canvas/layout? (so I can allow my customers to custom design their documents or reports).

Something being able to handle `<div></div>` blocks in a graphical way, similar to what tag editors do, returning a serialized array or something like that... well, anything would actually do, as long as I'm able to integrate it in our codebase, but that's the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything like what you are looking for but it shouldn't be too hard to create one.

I wouldn't go for a canvas based solution but rather on an absolutely positioned DIVs with drag and drop functionality and inline content editing.

You can easily serialize the content and position of the DIVs using Ajax.

The tutorial here is not what you are lookign for but it's the first step in the way: http://devheart.org/articles/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/

#### update

Obviously this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ is also an important reference

Comment: Wow... looks great as a starting point. Thank you very much for the valuable hint :)